# React Native FlatList won't scroll to the end of the header component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm having trouble getting my FlatList to scroll to the end of the header. This is what my component's styles are right now:

```
    <View style={styles.mainView}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          ListHeaderComponent={
            <>
              <View style={{minHeight: '40%'}}>
                <MapView
                  region={region}
                  showsUserLocation={true}
                  showsCompass={false}
                  style={styles.map}
                  provider={PROVIDER_DEFAULT}
                  scrollEnabled={true}
                  maxDelta={0.5}
                />
              </View>

              <View>
                <TextInput placeholder="Street address" />
                <TextInput placeholder="Apt/Sut/Bldg" />
                <TextInput placeholder="City" />
                <TextInput placeholder="State" />
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text>Save</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </>
          }
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainView: {
    height: devDims.height,
    width: devDims.width,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    maxHeight: devDims.height,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
});
```

I've tried switching to a ScrollView but the same problem occurs. Basically, I can scroll to the bottom of the header and see the content, but when I release my finger it immediately scrolls back to the top. What could be wrong with my styling?

It should be noted that `devDims` is simply the dimensions of the device.

Answer (score 0):

When you use any scrollview or faltlist, you have to use
`{{flexGrow:1}}` property of style which can cover all screen.

```
 <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}>
  </ScrollView>
```

or

```
 <FlatList contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}>
  </FlatList >
```

[flexGrow](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#flex-basis-grow-and-shrink)

[contentcontainerstyle](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle)